# Did I avoid a 1000 bounty as a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was doing the Dawnguard quest "Hide and Seek" in Solitude, and I decided I could try killing the vampire as a werewolf. Now, I transformed in the middle of the town square - probably not the best thing to do especially seeing as one of my houses, Proudspire, is just around the corner - but I apparently got a 1000 bounty, according to the onscreen notifications, then I killed the vampire.

The guards and townsfolk chased me out of town as a werewolf and I swam away from the port towards Hjaalmarch. When I had reverted to my normal self I went back to Solitude and no-one has batted an eyelid at me since.

Did I get away with it? What about that supposed 1000 bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems like I avoided it. I attacked a kid, hit her with my shield, and then I was ordered to pay 40 gold or go to jail - the 1000 didn't show up. Weirdly enough though, if I attack the guards they do nothing, unless I end up killing one of them. Maybe something to do with the camaraderie of the Imperials? Who knows.